# Nested model association performs self join instead of querying the correct model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

so i have this two models, called `Channel`. One is located inside a subdirectory, and another located directly at `/models` dir.

The code is this

```rb
class Products::Channel < ApplicationRecord
  include Productable

  belongs_to :channel, class_name: ::Channel.name, foreign_key: :channel_id
  paginates_per 5

  validates :is_available, inclusion: { in: [true, false] }

  def available?
    is_available
  end
end
```

However, when i try to create a new `Products::Channel` and pass in the corresponding `Channel` directory everything works (due to `foreign_key: :channel_id`). when i try to query the `channel` rails performs a self join.like this

```rb
3.0.1 :005 > Products::Channel.first.channel
  Products::Channel Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "products_channels".* FROM "products_channels" ORDER BY "products_channels"."id" ASC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
  Products::Channel Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "products_channels".* FROM "products_channels" WHERE "products_channels"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 5], ["LIMIT", 1]]
```

any idea why this issue occurs? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue (I believe) is this part:

```
class_name: ::Channel.name
```

The reason this is an issue is because `::Channel.name #=> 'Channel'`

When ruby goes to resolve this to a constant inside `Products::Channel` it resolves to `Products::Channel` because that is the closest constant `Channel` in the look up tree.

Instead the `.name` is unnecessary as you can reference the constant directly:

```
belongs_to :channel, class_name: ::Channel
```

I dropped the foreign_key because it can be inferred from the association name `channel`

Additionally I would highly recommend using true module nesting over [Constant]::[Constant] syntax. e.g.

```
module Products 
  class Channel 
    belongs_to :channel, class_name: ::Channel
  end 
end
```

The latter has a lot fewer surprises when it comes to constant look up in my opinion.

Comment: And using `class_name: "::Channel"` made it work!.